# How to make action bar and popups

Tags: ipad, popup

I want to do something similar to image right here:

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [mattgemmell.com](http://mattgemmell.com/images/ipad/inspector_text.jpg))</sub>

I want to have action bar and popups like this. Are there already existing components or is this accomplished using plain views? I tried to google this, but i cant find anything useful, some links and advices would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar along the top is probably a UIToolbar with a custom tint color. It's easy to add multiple UIBarButtonItems with icons or labels to a UIToolbar - you can do it all in Interface Builder with drag and drop.

The dropdown window is called a Popover. If you look up the documentation for UIPopoverView you'll see how to create them. All the hard work is done for you - you just specify the view controller that draws the contents, and where onscreen you want it to appear from.

Comment: I actually meant - how to make action bar that shows this pop up that has all mentioned controlls? The action bar that has icons of wrench, picture and i on it.